# PhoneGap não abre site externo!

Tags: html, apache-cordova, facebook

Estou começando com o PhoneGap, e encontrei um problema: meu app precisaria abrir uma página no facebook. Mas não consigo fazer o PhoneGap App abrir uma simples página da Globo.com (exemplo), mas pelo Desktop eu consigo normalmente!

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src *; object-src *; style-src *; img-src *; media-src *; frame-src *; font-src *; connect-src *">    
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <br><br>
        <a href="www.globo.com">GLOBO</a>

        <iframe src="www.google.com.br/"></iframe>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script>

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Meu config.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver essa situação?

---

**Resolvido!** O problema acredito que esteja no PhoneGap App, pois no apk do Android funcionou normalmente!

Comment: Não seria porque está faltando o `http://` no inicio do URL? Quando você usar `href="www.coisa.com"` ele irá para `phonegap/www.coisa.com`, EXEMPLO, ao invés de ir para `http://www.coisa.com`, que é o website.

Comment: Sim, já tentei também e não funciona. O <a> eu consegui mudar e fazer funcionar, com Jquery.

    $("#face").click(function() {
        window.open("https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/", "_system");
    });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guilherme, o PhoneGap na sua própria documentação possui uma explicação detalhada referente ao acesso de internet pelo Aplicativo. Segue o link:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#supported-cordova-platforms

Recomendo que leia, pois é de grande auxilio.

Execute os seguintes comandos no seu terminal, no diretório de seu aplicativo:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
$ cordova prepare
```

(Se for windows, não precisa do $)

E adicione a seguinte linha no seu `config.xml`:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Essa linha, basicamente te dá a autorização para acessar todas paginas da internet através do seu aplicativo.

NOTA: No seu `config.xml`, verifique se possui qualquer outra tag `<allow-navigation>`, se tiver, pode excluir ela e copiar a que eu passei em cima.

Answer (score 2):

No meu caso para funcionar eu inseri no xml essa linha

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.3.3"/>
```

E essa linha

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Converti no phonegap build, talvez ajude ^^